# Cauchy Schwarz Inequality for Vectors - Quadratic form Clarification

Tags: vectors, inner-products, quadratic-forms, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, discriminant

In one of the proofs of Cauchys Inequality that reduces vector inner product to a quadratic form:

$$0 \leq \langle u + \alpha,  u + \alpha \rangle = \langle u , u \rangle + 2 \alpha\langle u ,v \rangle + \alpha^2\langle v,v \rangle$$

Since any quadratic $$ a \alpha^2+2b\alpha + c $$ takes its minimal value @ $ c - \frac{b^2}{a} $ when $ \alpha = -\frac{b}{2a}$ ---- `(1)`

and the inequality should hold for even this minimum value of the polynomial
$$ 0 \leq \langle u,u \rangle - \frac {\langle u,v\rangle^2}{\langle v,v \rangle} \iff \frac {|\langle u,v \rangle|}{||u|| ||v||} \leq 1  $$ --- `(2)`

**Questions:**

Main Q) Am not confident how the equivalence is same. Please confirm the following the is correct thinking:
$$ 0 \leq \langle u,u \rangle - \frac {\langle u,v\rangle^2}{\langle v,v \rangle} $$
Take the `-` to the left, we get:
$$ \frac {\langle u,v\rangle^2}{\langle v,v \rangle} \leq \langle u,u \rangle  $$
Since in vector inner product of the same vector $\langle v,v \rangle$ = $|v|^2$ , thus:
$$ \frac {\langle u,v\rangle^2}{|v|^2} \leq |u|^2  $$
$$ \frac {\langle u,v\rangle^2}{|v|^2|u|^2} \leq 1  $$
Taking Square root on both sides:
$$ \frac {\langle u,v\rangle}{|v||u|} \leq 1  $$

Would the above be a correct mathematical deduction of how the equivalence is achieved?

Side Q) in `(1)` Is the minima of a Quadratic equation when its discriminant = `0`? Any link that helps show this please suggest.

Comment: To find the minimum of a quadratic polynomial, complete the square. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: Square root of $A^2$ is not necessarily $A$. Indeed $\sqrt{A^2}=|A|$ for all $A\in\mathbb R$.